# Gridview with layout (imageview + imagebutton) for every value

Tags: android, layout, gridview, imagebutton, adaptor

Is it possible to make a gridview that has instead of a grid of pictures, a grid of pictures with a small imagebutton below every one of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Short answer:* Yes. You can have an `ImageView` and an `ImageButton` in a `GridView`.

*Long answer:*

You will naturally have to create a custom `GridView` for that purpose.

For example:

Create an XML which will hold the container `GridView`, say, `grid.xml`:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridFriends"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

And, to define the contents of the `GridView`, create another XML layout which will hold the `ImageView` and the `ImageButton`. Say, `grid_items.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@null" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnDemo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" >
        </ImageButton>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, if you are familiar with the concept of custom `ListViews`, with a few modifications, you will be able to implement a custom `GridView` too. If you are not familiar with custom `ListViews` or `GridViews`, follow this tutorial to see how to create a custom `GridView`: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/29/custom-gridview-in-android-a-simple-example/. Or use this [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+custom+gridview+example&oq=android+custom+gridview&gs_l=hp.3.1.0j0i7j0l2.67.6157.0.7796.23.23.0.0.0.6.474.4796.0j14j5j2j2.23.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.mQ3YMh3tzDI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.bmk&fp=aa8f2157e742c828&biw=1440&bih=775) for more tutorials on the same.

**An important point here would be, if you need the `ImageButton's` to do a function when they are clicked, the `onClickListener` will need to be setup in the `Adapter`.**

Comment: thanks, this site: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/29/custom-gridview-in-android-a-simple-example/ + the xml's you gave me helped a lot in doing my custom gridview. Very good answer

Comment: How can I inflate the relative layout in the grid_items? I am getting this exception: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Comment: @Pria: You seem to be casting it wrong. If it is a `RelativeLayout`, you should be casting it as that. You seem to be casting a `FrameLayout`. Alternatively, post a new question and link to it here. I'll see if I can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

`GridView` shows a grid of `Views`. It can show anything that extends `View` class. It can show a `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` and an `ImageButton` inside it.