# How to add text to image in grid view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

well i have gridview , which pulls the images from server & display it in gridview,
i want to add related text to each image.it must look like the below image.
How to achive that ?

[image]

Comment: you need to create a custom "grid view item" layout for grid view and apply that custom layout item to your adapter of grid.

Comment: This could be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14808997/450534

Comment: First of all, What have you tried? Show us your homework which you have done if any.

Comment: Second,its custom GridView with Image and Text. Check: [Android – GridView example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/)

Comment: is adding text on your image solves your problem?

Comment: i'm able to load the images,just i want to append text to each image.

Comment: this link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145819/how-to-show-text-on-image

Answer (score 1):

in order to fill a GridView you got to create an item(Xml layout);
then in the adapter you'll got to inflate it and fill it up;
so you are able just to create a FrameLayout with an image and a textView with gravity bottom and background #66666666 where #AARRGGBB  AA-is an alfa chanel(transparecy);