# How to show Text on Image

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have written a code, in which i am showing images in GridView, but now i want to show text in bottom of every image.

And i want to show my Grid like this:

[image]

but getting like this **[also want to show Text for Image]:**

[image]

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="2" 
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what is the questions here ?

Comment: create custom layout for your GridView's item and put there image + TextView and populate them in your Adapter.

Comment: agree with @Android-Developer

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261088/gridview-with-two-columns-and-auto-resized-images

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a custom grid item layout which contains a textview to assign the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scaleType="cropCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#55000000" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here we have created a FrameLayout which has the imageview set to match the parent's dimensions, this will be the imageview that displays the photo. Next, there is a TextView which will be used to display the item title and that is aligned to the bottom of the FrameLayout.

Next, we need to edit your adapter to use this grid item layout and render the correct information.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Inflate the single grid item layout
    if (convertView == null) {  
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Set Image
    ImageView thumbnail = convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    if (thumbnail != null) {
        thumbnail.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    }

    // Set Text
    TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setText("Image Number: " + position);
    }

    return convertView;     
}
```

mLayoutInflater should be globally defined in your constructor using

```
mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Comment: This would be the most efficient way to do what you want, since using a custom adapter allows you to recycle views and customize your content.