# just want to ask that, can we add only one image in a GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

For example I already have 7 buttons in a `GridView`, i just want that in place of 8th and 9th button i get one image.
Is it possible to do anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible,

as pointed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809171/1638739):

> GridView shows a grid of Views. It can show anything that extends View
>   class. It can show a LinearLayout with an ImageView and an ImageButton
>   inside it.

but the only possible thing to achieve what you looking for is by creating a custom GridView that has a customized view element as pointed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809225/1638739):

> Create an XML which will hold the container GridView, say, grid.xml:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridFriends"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

And, to define the contents of the GridView, create another XML layout which will hold your elements, like Button and ImageView in your case: `grid_element.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
                    />
        <ImageView
                    />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

finally, after declaring the GridView and assigning `grid_element.xml` as the GridAdapter view type, just iterate over every element and set the Visibility of it's children as `Visible` , `Gone` respectively or `Gone`, `Visible` respectively according to if you want to make the Button visible or the ImageView. And to set the `onClick` for the Buttons:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
        if(position != 8 && position != 9){
           // do onClick work
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The same thing i was looking for